# How do you know if a DFA is minimizable or not?

Tags: computation-theory

[image: TOC]

This is one of the lectures in Theory of Computation where we need to transform epsilon-NFA to DFA. The table above shows the final result DFA. Based on the diagram, how do you know if you would need to do minimization or not ? What are the conditions whether to do minimization or not ?

Comment: Wouldn't you just go ahead and minimize it? You don't need to figure out whether minimization will help before you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the initial and final states and then draw the table filling algorithm 
for the given states and check whether on each transition they go to same kind of states i.e both final or both non-final and then if that is so then it is minimizeable and further check by giving different strings as input.
If they dont then it is already a minimized dfa and further no minimization can be done.